# Numpy error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (65,) (77,)

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I'm trying to generate a graph in IPython notebook for a .csv spreadsheet (easily found in kaggle = titanic_data.csv) and put below a summary of the steps I have done. First I imported the worksheet and took out some columns.

```
titanic_data = pd.read_csv("titanic_data.csv")
titanic_data_cleaned = titanic_data.drop(['Name','Ticket','Cabin','Fare','Embarked'], axis=1
```

Doubt: I tried to generate the percentage graph below but I could not solve the following error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (65,) (77,). I can not solve it, please if anyone can help, thank you very much.

```
totals = survivors_age_group + non_survivors_age_group

calculate_percentage1 = survivors_age_group
calculate_percentage2 = non_survivors_age_group


# Use calculate_percentage_function to calculate the percentage of total
data1_percentages = calculate_percentage1(survivors_age_group, totals)*100 
data2_percentages = calculate_percentage2(non_survivors_age_group, totals)*100

tick_spacing = np.array(range(len(age_labels)))+0.4

# Graph to percentage of survivors per class
ax2.bar(range(len(data1_percentages)), data1_percentages, alpha=0.5, color='g')
ax2.bar(range(len(data2_percentages)), data2_percentages, bottom=data1_percentages, alpha=0.5, color='r')
plt.sca(ax2)
plt.xticks(tick_spacing,  age_labels)
ax2.set_ylabel("Percentage")
ax2.set_xlabel("")
ax2.set_title("% of survivors by age group",fontsize=14)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly without a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), however it *looks* like the problem most likely lies in `ax2.bar(range(len(data2_percentages)), data2_percentages, bottom=data1_percentages, alpha=0.5, color='r')`.

Are `data2_percentages` and `data1_percentages` the same length?

Comment: No they aren't because survivors and not survivors are in the same colum,  but the amount of not survivors is bigger. How can I solve it or show using another numpy plot?

Comment: If you want to use `data1_percentages` as `bottom` in your second `.bar` call, it *must* be the same length as `data2_percentages`. Without being able to run the code, I can't tell you why they are different lengths. It's impossible to answer this question without a minimal working example. At the very least, provide a link to the data file.